# Django forms with grid layout

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to implement a grid layout for entering marks of students into my model. The model is described as:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
  is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=True)
  email = models.EmailField('email address', blank=False)
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)

class Student(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='student_profile')
  yoe = models.IntegerField('year of enrollment', choices=YEAR_CHOICES,
                          default=datetime.datetime.now().year)
  photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='student/%Y/')

class Paper(models.Model):
  semester = models.CharField(max_length=1)
  name_of_paper = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  max_pass_marks = models.IntegerField("Max Marks",validators=[MaxValueValidator(99)])

class Test(models.Model):      
  student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')
  paper = models.ForeignKey(Paper, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')
  dot = models.DateField("Date of Test")
  marks = models.IntegerField("Marks Obtained",validators=[MaxValueValidator(99)], default=0)
```

I want to be able to create a form with a grid layout where each row of the grid will have the students name followed by text boxes where users can enter the test scores obtained by students in each of the 'Paper' they have opted for. Obviously the test scores should then populate the 'Test' table/model. I am relatively new to django and cant really wrap my head around this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This is not related to django. This is about HTML and CSS.

Comment: Wont I have to make a dynamic form in django. One row for each of the students and also one column for each of the papers offered by the student?